# Buttons and inputs not inheriting the body's font-family

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me understand why the `user agent stylesheet` (in Chrome at least) is taking precedence over the `body` for `font-family` on [my site here](http://snakegamerecreation.org/snakegame.php)? I know it's easily fixed, but I'm trying to be elegant here.

Comment: Can you please add the code inline?

Comment: The only relevant code is: @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower); body {font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clause 6.1.1 [Specified values](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specified-value) of the CSS 2.1 specification defines as the first step: “If the cascade results in a value, use it.” Only after this will inheritance be considered. A browser style sheet (user agent style sheet) is conceptually part of the CSS cascade. So if it sets a value for `font-family` for an element, such as `input` or `button`, that value will be used, unless another style sheet sets it *for that element*.

Thus, if you want to use your font for `input` and `button` elements, too, you need to set e.g.

```
body, input, button {font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;}
```