# it seems like user agent stylesheet override the reset css code

Tags: css, next.js, reset, emotion

I'm working on nextjs project.

I tried to reset CSS in _app.tsx
my _app.tsx code is

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

import GlobalStyles from '@/styles/GlobalStyles'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}
```

and this is my GlobalStyles code

```
import { Global, css } from '@emotion/react'
import emotionReset from 'emotion-reset'

export default function GlobalStyles() {
  return (
    <Global
      styles={css`
        ${emotionReset}
        body {
          align-items: center;
          display: flex;
          font-family: 'SF Pro Text', 'SF Pro Icons', 'Helvetica Neue',
            'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
          height: 100vh;
          justify-content: center;
          margin: 0 auto;
          width: 375px;
        }

        #__next {
          align-items: center;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          height: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;
          padding: 0 16px;
          width: 100%;
        }
      `}
    />
  )
}
```

and this is my folder structure

```
src
 ┣ components
 ┃ ┗ ui
 ┃ ┃ ┣ button
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ index.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ styled.tsx
 ┣ pages
 ┃ ┣ register.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.tsx
 ┃ ┣ _app.tsx
 ┃ ┣ _document.tsx
 ┃ ┗ index.tsx
 ┣ styles
 ┃ ┗ GlobalStyles.tsx
 ┗ views
 ┃ ┗ register
 ┃ ┃ ┣ index.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┗ styled.tsx
```

I tried to test reset css by rendering the button component on the register page.
but it doesn't work.
[image]
It seems like the button's user agent sheet overrides my reset CSS code.
I wonder what is problem with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Initial value of `font-family` [depends on user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family#formal_definition), form elements will get their styles from the browser first. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28524331/3372050. You should add `font-family: inherit;` to your global css like:

```css
button,
input,
textarea,
select {
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

Or you can use a css reset eg.: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/